# Why does LibreOffice have no icon in Ubuntu dock?

Tags: icons, libreoffice, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I tried to add LibreOffice to my launcher applications. But it doesn't show the original LibreOffice icon, instead it shows blank icon as it shows the last icon in the luncher.

[image]

I want to change the icon to this one:

[image]

This what happens now:

[image]

Comment: @Kashan the icon *is* the (general)  icon of LibreOffice. The modules have more specific icons.

Comment: That *is* the original one. If you need to add writer, calc or whatever module, you need to add that one specifically.

Answer (score 2):

The icon currently added to the dock is the icon for "LibreOffice". It seems you want to add the icon for "LibreOffice Writer" instead.

To do that first remove the icon by right clicking and selecting "remove from favourites".

Then click on Activities and search for "LibreOffice Writer". Right click on the "LibreOffice Writer" icon and add this one to favourites instead.

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: I did that and the original icon back again. But there is one problem now. Once I open libreoffice writer, the blank old icon pops up again under the Libreoffice writer one. I will attach a photo to my post.

Comment: it feels like the original icon is just a link to the old blank one. Once I click on it it opens the old white blank one.

Comment: @Kashan Strange! I cannot reproduce that in my system. Try logging out and log in again. If this persists you might have to edit the `.desktop` file associated to Writer and add an extra `StartupWMClass=` line. For that I would suggest asking a new question.

Comment: @pomsky sorry for my late reply. Tried to log out and restart the laptop, no results. 
Just want to ask you something. How can someone change an icon on the luncher?

Comment: @Kashan The easiest way is probably by changing the icon theme completely. gnome-look.org is a great place to find many icon and other themes.

Comment: @pomsky thanks man. Did change the icon and all good now.

Comment: @pomsky I have done all you say in Ubuntu 19.04 without getting the expected results. All the libreoffice (write and calc) windows are gathered into a single white icon as the asker points. Did you find any other solution?

Comment: Well, I have reboot my system with xorg instead of wayland and works better. At least if the icons are added to the favorites bar beforehand the white icon does not appear

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu 19.04 with GNOME Shell 3.32.2 happens the same problem.

There is an [open issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/767) where writer says that Wayland only can access to the top level icons.

They suggest a workaround applying a patch that I did not try it yet. Anyway you can start Ubuntu with Xorg instead, if you don't mind using Wayland or not